# Is SMA dimension reduction (and, if not, what is it?)

Tags: terminology, dimensionality-reduction, moving-average

Needing to describe dimension reduction, strangely, the first example that popped into my head was a moving average. E.g. a 20-period moving average, takes 20 values, and reduces them to a single value. If I put each run of 20 values as one row in a matrix, then I am reducing from 2D to 1D.

But it has been nagging at me: I start with a list of numbers, and I end up with a list of numbers. So I've "reduced" from 1D to 1D?

So, are moving averages generally considered to be dimension reduction? If they are not, what type of process are they considered to be, and is there anything else in the same group that is not a moving average?  (E.g. something like k-means? What about FFT?)

Comment: No, they are not generally assumed to be dimension reduction but rather [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing). A SMA is "simply" a kernel smoother with a fixed width rectangular kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving averages are not generally assumed to be dimension reduction procedure but rather [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) one. It could be commented that a SMA is reducing the variability of a dataset in a way analogous with a [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) but once more this is filtering/smoothing procedure rather than dimension reduction. Ultimately a simple moving average is "simply" a [kernel smoother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother) with a fixed width [rectangular kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use). We can re-express a SMA in many different ways as it a special case of a convolution filter (e.g. as a [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) too) but that's mostly academic chit-chat. :)